# Can't run sudo wifi-radar under wayland

Tags: wayland, pygtk

I got this particular error when attempting to run `sudo wifi-radar`.

```
No protocol specified
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:794: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  self.window = gtk.Dialog('WiFi Radar', None, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:794: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  self.window = gtk.Dialog('WiFi Radar', None, gtk.DIALOG_MODAL )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:806: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.close_button = gtk.Button( "Close", gtk.STOCK_CLOSE )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:806: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.close_button = gtk.Button( "Close", gtk.STOCK_CLOSE )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:806: Warning: value "TRUE" of type 'gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property 'visible' of type 'gboolean'
  self.close_button = gtk.Button( "Close", gtk.STOCK_CLOSE )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:809: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.about_button = gtk.Button( "About", gtk.STOCK_ABOUT )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:809: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.about_button = gtk.Button( "About", gtk.STOCK_ABOUT )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:809: Warning: value "TRUE" of type 'gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property 'visible' of type 'gboolean'
  self.about_button = gtk.Button( "About", gtk.STOCK_ABOUT )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:812: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.preferences_button = gtk.Button( "Preferences", gtk.STOCK_PREFERENCES )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:812: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.preferences_button = gtk.Button( "Preferences", gtk.STOCK_PREFERENCES )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:812: Warning: value "TRUE" of type 'gboolean' is invalid or out of range for property 'visible' of type 'gboolean'
  self.preferences_button = gtk.Button( "Preferences", gtk.STOCK_PREFERENCES )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:827: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.icons_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:827: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.icons_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:833: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.ap_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:833: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.ap_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:839: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.signal_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:839: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.signal_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:845: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.mode_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:845: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.mode_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:851: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.protocol_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:851: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.protocol_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:857: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.channel_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:857: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.plist.append_column( self.channel_col )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:866: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  sb = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:870: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.new_button = gtk.Button( "_New" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:870: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.new_button = gtk.Button( "_New" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:874: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.edit_button = gtk.Button( "C_onfigure" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:874: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.edit_button = gtk.Button( "C_onfigure" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:879: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.delete_button = gtk.Button( "_Delete" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:879: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.delete_button = gtk.Button( "_Delete" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:884: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.connect_button = gtk.Button( "Co_nnect" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:884: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.connect_button = gtk.Button( "Co_nnect" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:887: GtkWarning: IA__gtk_settings_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.disconnect_button = gtk.Button( "D_isconnect" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:887: Warning: g_object_get: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  self.disconnect_button = gtk.Button( "D_isconnect" )
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_pango_context_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_font_description: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_base_dir: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_context_set_language: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_new: assertion 'context != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_text: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_attributes: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_alignment: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_ellipsize: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_single_paragraph_mode: assertion 'PANGO_IS_LAYOUT (layout)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_set_width: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: PangoWarning: pango_layout_get_extents: assertion 'layout != NULL' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_default_colormap: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_colormap_get_visual: assertion 'GDK_IS_COLORMAP (colormap)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_screen_get_root_window: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
/usr/bin/wifi-radar:920: GtkWarning: IA__gdk_window_new: assertion 'GDK_IS_WINDOW (parent)' failed
  self.window.show_all()
[1]    8059 segmentation fault  sudo wifi-radar
```

Comment: Also note that this is known "bug" of Wayland - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1713311 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use `xhost`

> The xhost program is used to add and delete host names or user names to the list allowed to make connections to the X server. In the case of hosts, this provides a rudimentary form of privacy control and security. It is only sufficient for a workstation (single user) environment, although it does limit the worst abuses. Environments which require more sophisticated measures should implement the user-based mechanism or use the hooks in the protocol for passing other authentication data to the server

`xhost` will print list of allowed names

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:yourusername
```

`xhost +si:localuser:root` should help in your case.

And after that you will see

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:root
SI:localuser:yourusername
```

And `sudo wifi-radar` will work as expected.

This is roughly one of the reasons you could see this error message.